# On wxTextCtrl max length callback

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've been working with wxTextCtrl and found one interesting thing. When I set max length as small number (250, 500, 10000) it works well. But when I put bigger numbers (20000, 100000), it doesn't work (I can go over the limit and no callback). Don't know how to fix it. Please, help.

wxWidgets 3.0.2

Windows

wxTextCtrl wxTE_BESTWRAP | wxTE_MULTILINE | wxBORDER_NONE | wxTE_AUTO_SCROLL | 
wxTE_AUTO_URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in file textctrl.cpp, method

```
bool wxTextCtrl::HasSpaceLimit(unsigned int *len) const
```

line which makes everything

```
return *len < 10001;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, of course, `SetMaxLength()` should work for any length, but it's really meant to be used with small lengths and single line text entry controls, e.g. to limit a country code to 2 or 3 letters. And in portable code you can't use it with `wxTE_MULTILINE` controls at all, as mentioned in the documentation, because this just doesn't work with GTK+.

So my advice would be to stop using it for something it wasn't designed for, even though, in principle, this could be a bug in wxMSW which could be fixed -- but for the reasons explained, it's a rather low priority bug.